# target values in CSS inside an inline element

Tags: css, targeting

I have a HTML of 
    `<span> Day Month </span>`

and for CSS I want to target Day seperately and Month seperately (apply different styles to them) **without changing the HTML**.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't. Not with pure CSS. Very easily with JavaScript or editing HTML

Comment: yep, this is what I thought too, but wanted to ask so as to be sure. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah its possible. You can follow this method.
Here `font-word` is not posible, that have no option in css. But we use `content` css property

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span {
color: orange;
    }
span:before
{
color: red;
content: "Day";
position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span>Day Month </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated: Here the fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgerd/2/)

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is that you did change the HTML to achieve this, so instead of `<span> Day Month </span>` you did `<span> Month </span>`

Comment: I accepted your answer as a reward for your effort and willingness to help. Of course I guess this is the limit of CSS and if the content inside the span was dynamically generated by say PHP we wouldn't be able to make use of the `content:blah blah` trick :)